# Subclassing QInputDialog.getItems

Tags: python, pyqt

QInputDialog.getItems is a static method and its "constructor" is:

```
(QString, bool ok) QInputDialog.getItem (QWidget parent, QString title, QString label, QStringList list, int current = 0, bool editable = True, Qt.WindowFlags flags = 0)
```

I would like to subclass it, but I can't find the way to:

- Display the dialog box
- Return True or False if the ok button is pushed or not

I tried something like that, but I haven't been very successful:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class DialogPerso(QtGui.QInputDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(DialogPerso, self).__init__()


    def getItem(parent, title, label, items, current = 0, editable = True, flags = 0):

        string = "prout"

        print(parent)
        print(title)
        print(label)
        print(items)

        return string, QtGui.QInputDialog.result()

    getItem = staticmethod(getItem)
```

I can only return the string for now. Any idea about how getting the value of the ok button, and how to display the dialog box ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. That's not a constructor; you probably mean the *signature* of the method. What do you mean when you say "how to display the dialog box ?" In the code you posted you do not create any dialog box(which you should do probably).

Comment: I edited my post to show you the entire class I'm trying to subclass. Yes, I do not create any dialog box, because I don't know how. The method is static, so there is no "self" in the parameters. I can't do self.show() so.

Comment: You have to create a new dialog. Either do `dialog = DialogPerso(....)` and then use `dialog.exec_()` to show it.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I now have the dialog box. But in getItem() I also have to return the user input: if he pushed "ok" or "cancel". How can I get this value ?

Btw, what is the difference between exec_() and show() ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this is really worth doing, but the following is a more or less equivalent to the C++ original:

```
class DialogPerso(QtGui.QInputDialog):
    @staticmethod
    def getItem(parent, title, label, items,
                current=0, editable=True, flags=0, hints=0):
        if 0 <= current < len(items):
            text = items[current]
        elif items:
            text = items[0]
        else:
            text = ''
        dialog = QtGui.QInputDialog(
            parent, QtCore.Qt.WindowFlags(flags))
        dialog.setWindowTitle(title)
        dialog.setLabelText(label)
        dialog.setComboBoxItems(items)
        dialog.setTextValue(text)
        dialog.setComboBoxEditable(editable)
        dialog.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.InputMethodHints(hints))
        if dialog.exec_() == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
            return dialog.textValue(), True
        return text, False
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of vague on why you want to subclass QInputDialog, but this is easy.

If you want to know if the user accetped or rejected the dialog, you can use the `accepted()` and `rejected()` methods directly. These are both inherited from QDialog which might be why you missed them. Fortunately, by subclassing QInputDialog these will be inherited by your class too:

```
d = DialogPerso(**args) #args set elsewhere
if d.rejected():
    print "The user didn't hit 'OK'
elif d.accepted():
    print "The user say 'OK', and entered %s" % d.result()
```